# Relating slit scan photography to linear algebra?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions

This should be ok but I thought I'd check, the FAQ suggests that it might not be.

I wish to ask a question regarding a simple form of photography (slit scan) and its equivalence to 3D linear transforms. This can be more about a 1D arc/grid/splay of rays ending at a point than an actual physical camera and photography elements such as exposure, exact lens shape or color balance are not relevant to this at all.

I think I'd find parts of the question confusing, complicated and difficult to ask without reference to the analogy of a slit scan camera though.

Comment: Sounds perfectly fine to me, as long as the question is mathematical in nature and any non-mathematical knowledge needed to understand it is specified in the question.